# Zero-filling Fourier Transform in NMR

Tags: physical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I understand zero-filling increases the resolution of an NMR signal in the frequency domain, but I fail to comprehend how. Why do the artifical points appear between the real points in the frequency domain? Is it a byproduct of the fast fourier transform algorithm? Can someone explain this to me? Thanks!